# Getting text on image how?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, image, text

```
**No error in this code**
```

**What I’m basically trying to do is get my text that says preapproved and put that onto my image the closest I got was I got my text behind the image but not on to my image. Was hoping I could get some help please and thank you.**

```
import React from ‘react’;
import Car from ‘./car_lot.jpg’
import Header from ‘./logo.png’
import Paperwork from ‘./sign_documents.jpg'
import Car_Galleryimg1 from './jeep.jpg'
import Car_Galleryimg2 from './bmw.jpg'
import Car_Galleryimg3 from './toyota.jpg'

import ImageGallery from 'react-image-gallery';

const images = [
  {
    original: Car_Galleryimg1,
    thumbnail: Car_Galleryimg1,
  },
  {
    original: Car_Galleryimg2,
    thumbnail: Car_Galleryimg2,
  },
  {
    original: Car_Galleryimg3,
    thumbnail: Car_Galleryimg3
  },
];
function Home() {
  return (

**Trying to get preapproved onto my image the closest I have gotten is getting the word preapproved behind my image but not onto it and that is what I’m trying to figure out**

      <div className=“home”>
      <img src={Header} className=“logo.png”/>
      <h1>Welcome to Exclusive Auto Sales</h1><link href=“https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <h3>Get pre-approved!</h3><img src={Paperwork} className="sign_documents"/>


      <h2>Get your dream car today
      we are here to help you!</h2>
      <ImageGallery items={images} />
      </div>




  );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do it using some CSS. Try this [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp) site.